# How to limit the size of downloaded items folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a requirement in IOS application. I have created a download manager. But after downloading each item I need to check and delete items if TotalSize of Downloaded assets > MaxSize allowed, one by one in FIFO manner.

How can i achieve this in best possible manner?

Each downloaded assets are categorized in some Category and there is Max size of Category that should not exceed.

Comment: Sort the contents of the folder by date by using `NSFileManager`, start from the back and while the total size is bigger than the max size allowed, delete the last file.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez If the content is in a single folder your approach will work. But at present some content are in same folder and others aren't basically at the time they are been downloaded by different parts of application there infomation regarding which category they fall in is saved in the database with their filepath. I need to also find and check the sizes of other assets that may be spread out.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez What would be better to save all the content in folders categorized with their category or to save their information in database and then follow up with database and filesystem deletion?

Comment: I'd say it'd be better to have it all in the same folder, with subfolders for categories, and when you have to purge you can recursively gather all the metadata, sort by date added, and remove the oldest. The database approach might work there's more room for error.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I agree to you point of keeping downloaded items in category folder this approach will remove lot of errors. But currently in my project there are certain files that are outside their folders. Hence i have to take database approach. Can you suggest how can i make Database and filesystem in sync and minimize error as much as possible.